# How to remove /~CpanelUserName from my .com domain url?

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

---

I just moved my website to VPS, but I noticed that it's adding my Cpanel username for some reason:

For Example: mysite.com/**~CpanelUserName**/articles/hello-world

I believe I have to do something to the .htaccess file

btw, I am using Drupal

**Note**: If I take out the `~CpanelUserName` from the url, it does display the article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this fixed itself when I uploaded an older mysql database backup. I checked my .htaccess file and it's the original, does not have the code @howlin provided. Seems like it was a database issue. Thanks @Howlin for trying to help. What caused this still remains a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^USERNAME/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I added that to .htaccess file, but it did not fix it. I am still seeing the /~CpanelUserName

Comment: Try doing a hard refresh on the page or trying it in a different browser

Comment: No luck, even when using a diff browser.

Comment: Does anything happen at all?

Comment: Where is your htaccess for located? Is it in the root directory?

Comment: it's located in the public_html folder

Comment: I have check and double check it and it works for me. Do you have any other rules in your htaccess file?